# how to have spring manage bean lifecycle instead of jersey

Tags: java, spring, jersey

I'm using jersey 2.17 on tomcat 8, and I'm having a problem with what I think should be a very straightforward and common use case.

I have various beans defined in a spring XML file. I've now annotated one of them to expose some methods as rest APIs. This is a singleton bean, with a reference to another bean injected in the spring XML configuration.

My rest APIs are working, but the problem is that every time one is invoked a new instance of the bean class is created, and my bean reference is null. My understanding is that this is because jersey is managing the lifecycle instead of spring, and I need SpringComponentProvider, which will then provide the singleton.

I included jersey-spring3-2.17.jar in my application, and I specified the spring package in the servlet configuration in web.xml, as follows:

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>my.rest.package;org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.tracing.type</param-name>
            <param-value>ALL</param-value>
        </init-param>        
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

I know that the jersey.config.server.provider.packages parameter is being picked up because the annotated class in my.rest.package gets found, but the SpringComponentProvider is apparently not being registered, because I'm still getting a new instance of my bean every time.

I tried specifying the class explicitly like this:

```
    <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringComponentProvider</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

That didn't change the behavior either.

Any insights or debugging suggestions appreciated.

UPDATE: I realized that the version of my spring jars was behind the version expected by my jersey jars, and I think that's the problem. Once I'm able to update spring, if that fixes it I'll close this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I finally was able to update my spring, it turned out that was not the issue. I had to add `@Component` as well as `@Singleton` to my resource in order for jersey to recognize it as a spring-managed singleton. This problem would never have arisen if I was using annotations for spring; it happened because I was using XML to create the spring beans.

Answer (score 1):

Jersey will create a new instance on each call regardless if you have an XML bean of the same class as singleton in spring context:

https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2331

Also see this response on how to change that behavior:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14739010/2879838

Within your Jersey Resource class, since you already added the jersey-spring dependency, you can simply add the `@Autowire` annotation on your member variable that you say is injected via XML file in spring.  This will spring-inject the dependency when Jersey instantiates the resource on each request.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Autowire does solve the injection problem, but I have a resource that does need to be singleton, and Singleton did not fix it. However your answer did lead me down another line of thought and I found the solution.