# How can 2 REST-interfaces share instances

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

We're planning an "REST"-Server and now have the problem, that we want different REST-Interfaces to share information.

As an example to make thing clearer

- We have an **Application-Class** that maps the URL: "http://.../MyRESTApplication" (with @ApplicationPath, extend Application)
- We have the interface **SessionMaker** that maps .../MyRestApplication/SessionMaker and that returns a sessiontoken and stores the tokeni in the **SessionMap**
- We have intefrace **DoThings** that maps to .../MyRestApplication/doThings?={token}
- We have a class **SessionMap** thats supposed to store the tokens and a timestamp.

This SessionMaker checks if user and password are correct and returns sessiontoken if so (this works). It's supposed to store the token in the sessionMap so that DoThings can access it. But **DoThings** can'T access that **SessionMap** instead,  a new instance is created.

---

How can we have **SessionMaker** and **DoThings** share the same **SessionMap**-instance.

I have 3 Ideas but don't know wich are even applicable.

1. Make SessionMaker and DoTHing singletons (right now there are in getClasses) in the ApplicationClass. Make an Instance of SessionMap and give it to both.
2. Try to fish it out of the Applicationcontext, but I don't know how.
3. Merge SessionMaker and DoThings into one, but that results in the antipattern "Blob"

---

The only other question that I found, which deals with a similar situation is:
[Jersey REST Server: instantiating resource classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14738482/jersey-rest-server-instantiating-resource-classes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [EJB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_JavaBeans)s for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks.This helped to know what so search for. In the end we went with CDI.